# Django-admin is not recognized

Tags: django

I am creating a python project ,  and I am seeing an error saying :
The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again

I have installed python is my system and as well as in VS code , I have also added path to enviroment variables , I am unable to find error

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439089/using-django-admin-on-windows-powershell

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes, chances are you are missing some environment variables; a workaround is to use the module itself as an entrypoint: `python3 -m django`

This will provide you with a list of the following commands; and a warning which doesn't matter for initializing a project.

So you would use `python3 -m django startproject <args>`

```
Type 'python -m django help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    optimizemigration
    runserver
    sendtestemail
    shell
    showmigrations
    sqlflush
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver
Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not
properly configured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. 
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).
```